# Question about putty and sort of auto login

Tags: putty

I'm using KITTY to auto login on putty which works fine but the auto login only works for the initial logon. So basically I login then have to login into a second thing so for example ssh "adress" it asks me for another password. Would it be possible to create a script that also automatically injects my password when I try loggin in on that server?

Comment: Yes, of course, but you will need to get a firmer grip on what is involved. You don't log-on PuTTY. Why? PuTTY is simply a terminal interface. It can communicate with hosts. You log-on/log-into hosts under some user-account. So please explain in clear terms which host you log into using what and where the ultimate problem is. Normally you will use public/private key authentication to eliminate the need to supply a password. But you will need a key-pair per host.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: To be more clear, I log in on a linux server that does system admin stuff for another company, now because I load putty keys this works fine, I login with the username and the server doesnt request a password. Now the problem is to do a different subsection of admin stuff I login something called stepstone. Now that is basically just a script running something like ssh "address username w/e" I think i'm new to the company so im not entirely sure. But when I do that it asks for a password everytime which is what i'm basically trying to avoid by making a new script that includes the password

Comment: Okay, you don't have a Linux username/password, public/private key issue, you have a application authentication issue. You may be able to script the login with `expect`, but as far as it being a specific programming question that anyone here can help with -- they would have to work at your company and know what application is asking for the authentication. If you are new to the company, remember, the only dumb question is the one that goes unasked. (based on 32 years of professional experience) Nobody is expected to know the nuances of a system they have never worked on.